# assigning static ip address using php

Tags: php, apache, archlinux

i want to statically assign the ip address of my arch linux using php. i want to change the ip by using netmask,interface,broadcast,address & gateway.the user puts up the values into a html page.the html page posts the data to the php page.i want to change the ip using this data. HOW TO DO THIS!!

Files also can be used!! right?

..i was thinking of writing directly into the rc.conf using files!!...will this work and how??..i have my arch linux up with apache & php..any of the help is appreciated!!...thanku..:)

Answer (score 3):

You should write yourself a shell-script and launch that via PHP, instead of trying to accomplish such a task with PHP itself.
If you don't know how to do that, you should ask a related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: shell script?? as in?...sorry...i dint get u...i want my page to have all the things needed to set up the ip statically.i will have netmask gateway and all that the client will input and server will run the php to set that ip.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use PHP to attempt to configure a server?? You should configure the server using pre-existing tools and commands that are designed for that purpose.

```
$su

# ifconfig <interface, tpyically eth0> down
# ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.105 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
# ifconfig eth0
```

You COULD wrap those commands in an `exec()` statement, but I don't see a PHP script having the necessary system permissions to complete them successfully.

Comment: You can also let PHP handle and access system files. But that would require a lot of manual configurations. But I wouldn't let a webserver or one of its modules administer my system either. As you said: their are better tools for such a task.

Answer (score 0):

In normal condition, you may be not able to do it from web server directly due to security.

There are several problems like permission on /etc files, security context of user in which apache run etc.

One secure way is to create cron task which will run under root account and regularly check for existence of some file which can be generated by apache (php).
Once file will appear you can reconfigure whatever using ifconfig within cron task with appropriate privileges based on content o this file.

Don't forget that your apache should be configured to use all interfaces and not realy on IP based VirtualHosts or you will immediately lose connection to it.